# ElasticSearch SDK vs Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a question on ElasticSearch Plugin. What is difference between SDK and plugin from ElasticSearch?

We have used a 3rd party plugin which was installed on ES nodes. Now we are planning to replace that function with custom development. So the question should we replace with SDK and install on the application side or create a plugin and install on ES nodes.

Thank you .. Appreciate your response..